# Migrating Data from Rails 2 (Production) to Rails 4 from ground up

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-migration

I have kind of a tricky question. I "inherited" a Ruby on Rails app written for v2.3.11. So far so good, but it has been on that version for a number of years now, it has hundreds of users and lots of data that cannot be lost. The app was using very old versions of gems, being one of them the one that controls users, passwords, etc (kind of live Devise, but OLD!).

So, I had to rebuild this from scratch. That means, I'm using my own authentication system (no Devise or gems) and other approach. So, here comes the question. How can I migrate this from the old system to the new one? I can't lose information. Do you guys have any idea how to deal with this kind of issue? I don't want to tell users to register once again and having lost all their entries, preferences, etc. Database is MySQL. Guess I will stick to it however, if possible to use PgSQL, even better.

Any advise will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks again!!

Tom

Comment: and this legacy website has thousands of unit tests, all ready to pass on the new system, right?

Comment: Nope, it has very little to no tests. The new one I'm creating does have tests using rspec/capybara for model and fixtures.

Comment: Please only use capybara to test radical JS in your browser. All the rest of the tests should use RSpec and the "mock the server" pattern, where you call `get :index`, and the system calls the same controller handler that the routes would have.

Comment: I would spend a while adding low-level tests to the original app. If there was actually a business requirement for Rails 4, I would then copy each test into the new system, and pass it by copying individual lines of code from the original app to the new one.

Comment: Phil, I'm using capybara to test interactions on the views which also validates in some form, the controller (basic tests).
As for the suggestion, thanks. I will be trying small tests on the old app however, a friend of mine suggested me to use this:
https://github.com/rtomayko/replicate

May be worth it.